# × TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React component that receives data, maps through it and prints out bootstrap cards containing the data in the objects that come through.  However I have a problem that the data being returned is not allowing me to call `.map` (reporting an error `TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function`) even thought when I `console.log` the data it seems to be an array.

My code is below, as is the data shown in console.log.  I've read other questions on SO and the general answer seems to be that the data is not an array - but mine seems to be.

I've tried it with converting the data to an array `const data = Array.from(this.props.data);` and then `<CardDeck>{data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>` and this gets me further, but then I get errors `TypeError: Cannot read property '$numberDouble' of undefined` which relates to areas in the data such as

```
 "manufacturer": "Panini",
"number": {
  "$numberDouble": "16"
},
```

can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here?  I am getting the data from props, not from state - see image below

[image]

I can also print the data to the screen via

```
return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Hello {JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</h1>
        {/* <CardDeck>{this.props.data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
        {/* <CardDeck>{data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
      </Container>
    );
```

[image]

*Code*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CardDeck from "react-bootstrap/CardDeck";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import ListGroupItem from "react-bootstrap/ListGroupItem";
import { Image, CloudinaryContext, Transformation } from "cloudinary-react";

class CardColumns extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  loading: "",
  error: "",
  data: null,
  username: "",
};
}

componentDidMount() {
this.props.loadCardData(this.props.path);
}

render() {
// const data = Array.from(this.props.data);
// const data = this.props.data;
console.log("HERE IS DATA " + JSON.stringify(this.props.data));
const renderCard = (card, index) => {
  return (
    // TODO: Looks at setting default heght (white space? on images so the last two classes below can be removed)
    <Col className="container-fluid mt-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
      {/* <Card key={index} className="box"> */}
      <CloudinaryContext cloudName="dkwmxhsem">
        <Card
          style={{ width: "18rem" }}
          key={index}
          className="box h-100"
          border="danger"
        >
          <Card.Header>
            {card.brand} - {card.series}
          </Card.Header>
          <Card.Img
            variant="top"
            src={`${card.image_path}${card.card_id}.jpg`}
            fluid
          />

          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>
              {card.player} (#
              {card.card_number.$numberDouble}) {card.variation}
            </Card.Title>
          </Card.Body>
          <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
            <ListGroupItem>
              <b>Print Run - </b>
              {card.print_run.$numberDouble}
            </ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>
              <b>Career Stage -</b> {card.career_stage}{" "}
            </ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>
              <b>For Trade -</b> {card.forTrade}
            </ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
          <Card.Footer className="text-muted ">{card.team}</Card.Footer>
        </Card>
      </CloudinaryContext>
    </Col>
  );
};

return (
  <Container>
    <h1>Hello {this.props.num}</h1>
    <CardDeck>{this.props.data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>
  </Container>
);
}
}
export default CardColumns;
```

*Output of console.log*

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532c82c81067eafdb896"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Tre-2140",
    "brand": "National Treasures",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "100"
    },
    "career_stage": "Veteran",
    "forTrade": "Yes",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "16"
    },
    "player": "Trent Williams",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "25"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Century Materials",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jinsdvs@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Holo Silver",
    "year": "2010"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f78532d82c81067eafdb906"
    },
    "card_id": "Was-Rya-6543",
    "brand": "Playbook",
    "card_number": {
      "$numberDouble": "85"
    },
    "career_stage": "Rookie Card",
    "forTrade": "",
    "image_path": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dkwmxhsem/image/upload/t_Card Resize/v1599758190/",
    "manufacturer": "Panini",
    "number": {
      "$numberDouble": "80"
    },
    "player": "Ryan Kerrigan",
    "print_run": {
      "$numberDouble": "299"
    },
    "purchase_date": "Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020",
    "series": "Rookie Signatures",
    "status": "Own",
    "team": "Washington Football Team",
    "type": "Auto",
    "user": "jsdvsdv@gmail.com",
    "variation": "Base",
    "year": "2011"
  }
]
```

Comment: `data: null,` to `data: [],`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  I've made that change but no difference.  I am getting the data from props, not state.  I've added an image to the original question to show the props on the component

Comment: So check to see if `this.props.data` before you use it in the template

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to be there. If I run return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Hello {JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</h1>
        {/* <CardDeck>{this.props.data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
        {/* <CardDeck>{data.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck> */}
      </Container>
    );  I get the result I have added to the original question.  But I can't operate on it with `.map`

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize data as an empty array

`this.state = { loading: "", error: "", data: [], username: "", }; }` 
i hope that will be helpful for you

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  I've made that change but no difference.  I am getting the data from props, not state.  I've added an image to the original question to show the props on the component

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initializing an `array` with `null` is not a good practice.

Rather try to initialize data with the type it is expected to be.

```
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  error: "",
  data: [],
  username: "",
};
```

Another thing is, that in modern JS (ECMA2020) you can prevent from getting an `Cannot read property X of null.undefined` simply by use of **[optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)**.

```
<CardDeck>{this.props.data?.map(renderCard)}</CardDeck>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, you'r right about `array:null` - sorry I should have spotted that myself.    I've tried the method you suggested but get a similar error to before `TypeError: _this$props$data.map is not a function`

Comment: the reason might be that you have the data prop in a `state`, but you are mapping over `props`. Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling map in wrong way ,did you try to display it as an arrow function `this.state.data.map((renderCard) => renderCard))` ?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `<CardDeck>{this.props.data.map((renderCard) => renderCard)}</CardDeck>` but I still get `TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function`